# What is the best way to show a lot of JSON data in a mobile app, without showing all at once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, phonegap

I am building a mobile app. I'm using PhoneGap and HTML/jQuery for full context. The content I am pulling into a screen on the app is coming from JSON. The JSON output has more than 100 articles to show. Obviously when I pull in all content, it takes many seconds to load all content. I am reaching out to the community to learn what methods I can use to show this data easier.

Should I break the data into 10 article chunks, and force user to click 'load more' button to load more data? If so, then would each button click on 'load more' be a new JSON call? Is this bad practice?

Or would I load all 100+ articles, then set it via jQuery to only show 10 at a time, and when user clicks 'load more' the jQuery will show more content?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: to reduce the json data size, it's best to do server-side pagination as not to slow down the user experience.

Comment: if you can reach the server you could user some pagination if not ; there is no thing you can do

Comment: It depends on the size of each article. Does an article take up 20% of the screen size? or > 100% ? I recommend "pulling" (get/fetch) only the content that immediately fills the page and a little down the page so scrolling is uninterrupted, there is no exact measure it is an art. Then either a "load more" button, or have it just load another article when the user is near the bottom of the page.

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell the user sees about 2-3 articles per the screen height, then has to scroll down the page to view more articles. so the point i am trying to wrap my head around is: when user scrolls down to view more (per your example) or clicks 'load more' to view more articles - is each time i load more articles a new ping to JSON? or am i controlling this loading via jquery to hide/show?

Comment: JSON is data. jQuery is a library to help with DOM manipulation, but also has ajax. It seems you are talking about using ajax (with jquery) to GET some JSON data, and then using jQuery to alter the DOM with this JSON. I don't know what your code nor the JSON data structure you have looks like so I can't really help. Does this demystify it at all or did I make it worse?

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell i've already written ajax to get the JSON data and i have it printing in my app. life is great. i just need to learn the concept of breaking up what the user sees so they dont see all 100 articles at once. im simply trying to learn what concept/procedure i should use in this case. would my jQuery break it up and show more on 'load more' trigger? or would each time they click 'load more' it is a new JSON call? thanks for your time in explaining this to me...

Comment: Well the JSON data should be decoupled from the view/display. So, you can GET 100 articles with ajax, check network speed in dev tools (I use chrome which has network throttling for mobiles) - if 100 articles takes too long in your opinion for your target speed then you will want to try a smaller amount of articles at a time, e.g. 20, or 5? Test the network speed and see what works best. Multiple ajax GETs are not bad, but if they are very frequent then it can be an issue.

You will want to only make the ajax request if you haven't yet loaded the articles, so I suggest in the client .js ....

Comment: I think we should move to chat because of this conversation lengt. maybe here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17/javascript ?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161728/room-for-george-campbell